# How to Enable/Disable Button on MaskedTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a maskedTextBox and a Save button. Now i want to enable Save button if user enter something and disable if the maskedTextBox is empty. I have done that for textBoxes on a textChanged Event of a textbox and work properly but i am not able to do that on a masked TextBox textChanged Event. Here is my code. Please help

```
private void mtbCNIC_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mtbCNIC.Text == "")
        {

            btnSave.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {

            btnSave.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code should work fine, Are you sure the event is hooked

Comment: Code looks fine. Did you debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, checking if text has value is not such useful, you need to have a valid input to enable the button. I prefer to rely on:

```
this.button1.Enabled = this.maskedTextBox1.MaskCompleted;
```

> Mask is 00000-0000000-0

For such a specific mask you can simply Simply exclude `-` and `_` from text and check for length:

```
var str = this.maskedTextBox1.MaskedTextProvider.ToDisplayString();
this.button1.Enabled = str.Replace("-", "").Replace("_", "").Length > 0;
```

Comment: yeah it did well but i want that whenever a user enter a single input, Button Enables and when he/she remove , it disable @Reza

Comment: What's the `Mask` value?

Comment: `Mask` is 00000-0000000-0

Comment: Simply exclude `-` and `_` from `Text` and check for length.

Comment: See the sample code. Keep in mind `this.button1.Enabled` should be `false` at start.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that `Text` is also returning the mask characters, so although the user has not set any text, there is still the text from those characters. (You can confirm this by adding a breakpoint and checking `Text`)

You should be able to get only the user inputted part of the text by changing the `TextMaskFormat` property before the check, and then setting it back afterwards.

**EDIT:** Unfortunately, changing the `TextMaskFormat` seems to also fire the `TextChanged` event, which can cause a stack overflow if not handled carefully. This can be avoided by having a flag to suppress the event code, something like this:

```
bool suppressTextChanged = false;
private void mtbCNIC_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (suppressTextChanged)
        return;

    suppressTextChanged = true;
    mtbCNIC.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
    btnSave.Enabled = mtbCNIC.Text != string.Empty;
    mtbCNIC.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.IncludeLiterals;
    suppressTextChanged = false;
}
```

Comment: I did the same bro but now it throws `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll` Exception @mus

Comment: @khaafi: Ok, I fixed the issue, but now it becomes a bit cumbersome, so the other answer is probably better. However, this solution is generic and doesn't require the code to know about the specific mask details.

Comment: Thanks buddy for your time and help, if you want to share that method too, i'll be glad @musefan